# How do I reload images in an email?

Tags: thunderbird

If I accidentally click "Show Remote Content" on an unread email while not connected to the internet, images in the message fail to load... but that button also disappears. How can I reload them later? I haven't found an option for that.

Comment: Try to mark this particular mail as 'unread' which might do the trick?!

Answer (score 1):

I tried replicating your situation by going into offline mode, clicking "Show Remote Content" and then switching back to online mode. It loaded the images automatically. If that didn't happen then I think it is a bug in Thunderbird and you should file a bug with it's developers.
Have you tried restarting Thunderbird?

Comment: I hadn't thought about restarting, although when I switched to another message then switched back, they loaded automatically. I don't remember that (or anything else) working in the past...oh well. Thanks for the advice anyway.